# mips - array value print, why occured this problem?

Tags: mips

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUdL1.png)

and this is my code

I don't understand this text,and don't know how solve this problem.

please help me.

I can't find where the problem is.

```
    .globl main
.data
A:  .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
B:  .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

str1:.asciiz"Please, type a number for g:"
str2:.asciiz"Please, type a number for h:"

str3:.asciiz"The 1st result is:"
str4:.asciiz"The 2nd result is:"

.text
main:

li $v0,4  #print str1
la $a0,str1 #str1
syscall

li $v0, 5 #input g
syscall
move $s1, $v0 #$s1= g 

li $v0,4  #print str2
la $a1,str2 #str2
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s2, $v0 # $s2 = h 

la $t2, A
la $t3, B

sub $t0,$zero,$s1 #$t0 = 0 -g
move $s0,$t0 # f = -g
sll $t0,$s2,2 # t0 = 4 * h
lw $t0,0($t0) # t0 = B[h]
add $s0,$s0,$s5 # f = -g + B[h]

sll $t1,$s1,2 # t1 = 4 * g
add $t1,$t1,$s7 # t1 = address of B[g]
lw $t1,0($t1) # t1 = B[g]
addi $t1,$t1,1 # t1 = B[g]+1
sll $t1,$t1,2
add $t1,$t1,$s6
lw $s0,0($t1) # f= A[B[g] +1]

li $v0,4  #print str3
la $a2,str3 #str3
syscall

li $v0,1 # print result B[h] - g
syscall

li $v0,4  #print str4
la $a3,str4 #str4
syscall

li $v0,1 # print result  f= A[B[g] +1]
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall
```

Is it because I used the $to register too much?

In my program, after receiving an index value and performing an operation,

It is a program that outputs the value of the index.

Comment: `lw $t0,0($t0) # t0 = B[h]` <-- `$t0` does not hold the address of `B[h]` at that point.

Comment: Single step in the debugger to find unexpected issues

Comment: so, how can I solve that porblem? please help me...